# How to Get all Enum Values assign to my model return as List in c#?

Tags: c#, enums

I was planned to fill my country List drop down using Enum. So i need Enum value description and that index value.
**My Conditions:**

1. I want all Enum Value description with index  number value.
2. I don't want value of Enum only i need description and index.

**My Enum :**

```
public enum CountryListEnum
    {
        [Description("United Kingdom")]
        UnitedKingdom = 0,
        [Description("United States")]
        UnitedStates = 1,
        [Description("Afghanistan")]
        Afghanistan = 2,
        [Description("Albania")]
        Albania = 3,
    }
```

**My Model :**

```
public class CountryModel
    {
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What's stopping you?

Comment: what is an enum index ?

Comment: @lzzy I don't know how to do . I am expecting  generic in single line of code like generic

Comment: @TheGeneral that 0 , 1, 2 .. that values

Comment: I need that index values to country id and description value to countryName

Comment: @BalakrishnanG so you want to return all the values in a list or a dictionary?

Comment: @preciousbetine Yes . But i want to return as my Model . Like List<CountryModel>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should help you with an implementation.

```
        foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CountryListEnum)))
        {
            CountryModel myModel = new CountryModel();

            myModel.CountryId = item.GetHashCode();
            myModel.CountryName = item.ToString();
        }
```

**Edit**

As others have pointed the above will not retrieve the description. Here is an update in how to implement the retrial of description attribute.

```
        foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CountryListEnum)))
        {
            CountryModel myModel = new CountryModel();

            myModel.CountryId = item.GetHashCode();

            var type = typeof(CountryListEnum);
            var memInfo = type.GetMember(item.ToString());
            var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
            var description = ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[0]).Description;

            myModel.CountryName = description;
        }
```

Comment: This get the UK country name as "UnitedKingdom" (without the space) rather than "United Kingdom". Maybe that's good enough, but why would you have the description then?

Comment: He looking for the get item 'Description',  check my answer

Answer (score 1):

To get the index value, you can just cast the enum to an int. Getting the description attribute is a little more involved. Maybe something like this

```
public enum CountryListEnum
{
    [Description("United Kingdom")]
    UnitedKingdom = 0,
    [Description("United States")]
    UnitedStates = 1,
    [Description("Afghanistan")]
    Afghanistan = 2,
    [Description("Albania")]
    Albania = 3,
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (var country in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CountryListEnum)).Cast<CountryListEnum>())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Index: {(int)country}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Description: {GetDescription(country)}");
    }
}

public static string GetDescription(Enum value)
{
    Type type = value.GetType();
    string name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
    if (name != null)
    {
        System.Reflection.FieldInfo field = type.GetField(name);
        if (field != null)
        {
            if (Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field,
                typeof(DescriptionAttribute)) is DescriptionAttribute attr)
            {
                return attr.Description;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, this is what you looking for.

```
var model = new List<CountryModel>();
foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(CountryListEnum)))
{
    model.Add(new CountryModel
    {
        CountryId = (int)item,
        CountryName = ((DescriptionAttribute)item.GetType().GetField(item.ToString()).GetCustomAttribute(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false)).Description
    });
}
```

Comment: I can't compile this. It complains that the parameter for GetCustomAttribute should be a bool - not a Type.

Comment: @HansKilian My mistake, now you can copy it.